# Query to Find Out How Many Days Until Database Is Full

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using my central MDW database I am trying to make a query that will be able to calculate the number of days until all my databases free space will be full. Currently the query I have is overly complicated and takes long to run.

I am wondering if there is a simple solution using the following columns to calculate this. Columns I have are:

- row_number
- snapshot_time
- instance_name
- database_name
- dbsize
- current_usage

All tables are found in the MDW database. 
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your current approach? e.g. Are you assuming linear growth?

Comment: yes just the linear growth from snapshot sizes over the course of a year. Only issue is, i have a dataset with 65 million rows, so im looking a simple and effective solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to start building a history of the dbsize vs current_usage metrics by day (or more incremental if needed).  Only then will you be able to make educated calculations for projected dates.

Otherwise you'll essentially just be setting a "hard-coded" linear curve that won't really be precise enough.

Basically, have a stored procedure that takes a snapshot of the current dbsize, current_usage and inserts it into a historical table.  Once you have enough data, you'll be able to use that data to make your projections.

Comment: I think they'd need some hand holding on how you are meant to make projections. I think they know they have to, they're just not sure how to.